# Why HttpContext values are lost during AJAX call after Adding masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

It's been several days since I am trying to resolve this issue.
I have a page that is a mail inbox in the website. You can send messages to your friends from the list like on facebook.

It has AJAX code in a js file, 2 ashx files, and aspx, aspx.cs files.

I was using facebox pop up when a user wanted to send a message to a friend.
Now I changed the UI removed facebox and added a masterpage so that now the page is like any other page on the site. But after adding a masterpage to messages.aspx page
the values of HttpContext become null after I click on send message.
They are working fine when the page first loads that shows friends list and previous messages. It's when I fire a js function to save the message entered by clicking send that it's lost.

in message.aspx page I use 3 hidden fields:

```
<script>
    function SavePostedMessage() {
        var SenderAccountID = $("#hdnSenderID").val();
        var ReceiverAccountID = $("#hdnReceiverID").val();
        var Days = $("#hdnDays").val();
        var body = GetmessageData();
        if (body != null || body != "")
            SaveMessageInDatabase(SenderAccountID, ReceiverAccountID, body, Days);
    }
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSenderID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnReceiverID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDays" runat="server" />

<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="SavePostedMessage()">

    <div style="height: 25px; width: 85px; float: left; margin-top: 28px; padding-top:     5px; background: #01B2E5; text-align: center;" id="uploadifyContainer">
        <span style="color: White; font-size: 12px;font-weight:bold; margin-left: 5px; border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;"  id="Content_lblAddPhoto">Send</span>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

In messages.aspx.cs I put in page_load the code to register a js function:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this,
    typeof(string),
    "Play",
    "javascript:GetMessageConversation('" + Request.QueryString["AccountID"] + "','" + _userSession.CurrentUser.AccountID + "','7');", true);
```

In Ajax.js I defined

```
function GetMessageConversation(SenderAccountID, ReceiverAccountID, Days) {
    $("#hdnSenderID").val(SenderAccountID);
    $("#hdnReceiverID").val(ReceiverAccountID);
    $("#hdnDays").val(Days);
    $("#divPostComment").show();
    setSelected("trUser" + ReceiverAccountID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MessageFacebox/GetMessageConversation.ashx",
        data: 'SenderAccountID=' + SenderAccountID + "&ReceiverAccountID=" + ReceiverAccountID + "&Days=" + Days,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#messageconversationdata').html(data);
            Scrollbottom();
        },
        error: function (errordata) {
            alert('Sorry some error occurred');
        }
    });
}

function SaveMessageInDatabase(SenderAccountID, ReceiverAccountID, Body, days) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MessageFacebox/SaveMessage.ashx",
        data: 'SenderID=' + SenderAccountID + "&ReceiverID=" + ReceiverAccountID + "&Body=" + Body,
        success: function (data) {
            GetMessageConversation(SenderAccountID, ReceiverAccountID, days);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Sorry some error occurred');
        }
    });
}
```

In GetMessageConversation.ashx

`context.Request.Form["SenderAccountID"]` and `context.Request.Form["ReceiverAccountID"]` return stored values

```
Account senderAccount = _accountRepository
    .GetAccountByAccountID(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form["SenderAccountID"]));

Account receiverAccount = _accountRepository
    .GetAccountByAccountID(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form["ReceiverAccountID"]));
```

But in SaveMessage.ashx

```
Account senderAccount = _accountRepository
    .GetAccountByAccountID(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form["SenderID"]))   ;

Account receiverAccount = _accountRepository
    .GetAccountByAccountID(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form["ReceiverID"]    ));
```

`context.Request.Form["SenderID"]` and `context.Request.Form["ReceiverID"]` have null values.

the first one loads when the page is first accessed. The save function is called when user enters a message and click on send button in messages.aspx

All works fine without a master page. Once I add masterpage file to messages.aspx the code stops working.

Thanks in advance.